# SQL help, left join with filter

Tags: sql, oracle

Please have a look at the SQL in the SQLFiddle link below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22e094/4

My goal is to get all the records from Table1, and if SecId exists in Table2, join only if the status is 'Y'.

Result should be that it pulls from table 1: ID 1 and 2. And for ID 1, it successfully left joins Table2 and pulls 'Y'

As you can see in the fiddle, I tried 3 different ways but can't seem to get it.

It's got me stumped... Help would be awesome! :)

Comment: If it is Oracle, why tag it as MySQL?

Comment: Please post the expected results in tabular form, because your description is unclear

Comment: @Niagaradad I had issues with the Oracle option in SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left join, with just the join condition in the `ON` clause, is fine.

But then, you said you want to keep the rows where `status` is `'Y'` *only when the* `secid` *exists in* `table2`. So this means you also want to keep the rows where the `secid` from `table2` is `NULL`.

`select *` won't fly, because you have columns by the same name, `secid`, in both tables. You must distinguish them (by giving them aliases - or at least one of them; I gave aliases to both of them) if you need to reference them in the `where` clause, or anywhere else in the query, to break the ambiguity. And, since the aliases can only be given in the `SELECT` clause, which is evaluated after the `WHERE` clause, you need to do the left join in a subquery.

```
select id, secid_a, secid_b, status
from   ( 
         select a.id, a.secid as secid_a, b.secid as secid_b, b.status
         from   table1 a left join table2 b 
                         on a.secid = b.secid
       )
where  status = 'Y' or secid_b is null;
```

Comment: Awesome! That's it! I didn't think about using a select to filter the results of a select.

Comment: @Gvdk - This is called "a query with a subquery" or "nested queries" and is a very common technique in SQL. You'll use it all the time.